# Why is this sleep function not working when I try to animate rain?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func click(sender: UIButton) {
    for var x = 0; x<100; ++x{
        r1.center.y += 0.2
        usleep(10000)
    }
}
```

I am using Swift in Xcode 7.0 beta. I used a `UIButton` to test it and simplified it down to one raindrop. When I click I want it to move smoothly (as best as I can get it) downwards.

Right now though, it just waits for all the `usleep(10000)` functions to finish (100 of them) so it doesn't move for 1 second and then it moves 20px downwards. Am I using the `sleep()` function (`usleep()` actually) wrong or do I have to use a different type of wait function to get the animation to work properly?

It's worth mentioning I get no errors whatsoever when I run the code in the simulator.

Comment: Don't ever call `sleep` or `usleep` (or anything to that effect) on the main thread. As Martin R already pointed out in his answer below, you need an animation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI is updated only when program control returns to the main event
loop. Therefore your modifications to `r1.center` will become visible
only when the `click()` method returns.

Also you are blocking the main thread for a long time, which is generally bad because no events are processed and the UI is not updated, so the
app becomes unresponsive. 
Blocking the main thread for too long may cause the program to be killed by the OS.

You can use a *timer* instead with a callback function which updates the position.

Alternatively (as mentioned in a comment), use
[Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: class func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval,
                                   target target: AnyObject,
                                 selector aSelector: Selector,
                                 userInfo userInfo: AnyObject?,
                                  repeats repeats: Bool) -> NSTimer                                   I tried thing like that which is from apple's documentation website but I always get an error, most of the time it has to do with adding commas but I think I don't fully understand the syntax or how to format it. Can you help? @Martin R

Comment: @CoolPenguin: I have tried to answer your question *"Why is this sleep function not working"*. You should find many examples for NSTimer here on SO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945310/countdown-with-several-decimal-slots-using-nstimer-in-swift. If you still cannot figure it out, please ask a new question because it is a different problem.